# Understanding $\sigma$-field on $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading Section 14.3, p. 359 of *Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes*, by Le Gall, and trying to understand this paragraph:

> Let $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d \right)$ denote the space of all continuous functions from $\mathbb R_+$ into $\mathbb R^d$. We equip $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d \right)$ with the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal C$ defined as the smallest $\sigma$-field for which the coordinate mappings $\mathrm w \mapsto \mathrm w(t)$, from $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R \right)$ into $\mathbb R$, are measurable, for every $t \in \mathbb R_+$.

I am not convinced the definition of $\mathcal C$ makes sense. In particular, I think the second sentence is supposed to read "coordinate mappings $\mathrm w \mapsto \mathrm w(t)$, from $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d \right)$ into $\mathbb R^d$, are measurable". I will try to spell out my understanding below.

We have $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d \right) := \left\{ f \colon \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R^d \colon f \text{ is continuous} \right\}$. For every $t \in \mathbb R_+$, we have a map $c_t \colon C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R \right) \to \mathbb R$, defined by $c_t(\mathrm w) = \mathrm w(t)$.

We want a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal C$ on $C\left( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d \right)$ such that the $c_t$ are measurable. More precisely, if $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb R$, then we want $\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb R_+} \left\{ c_t^{-1}(B) \colon B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\right\} \in \mathcal C$. Therefore, we set

\begin{align*}
\mathcal C := \sigma \left( \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb R_+} \left\{ c_t^{-1}(B) \colon B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\right\} \right).
\end{align*}

My issue is that $c_t^{-1}(B) = \left\{ f \in C\left(\mathbb R_+, \mathbb R\right) \colon c_t(f) \in B \right\} \subseteq C\left(\mathbb R_+, \mathbb R\right)$ is a subset of the wrong space. We need sets of subsets of $C\left(\mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d\right)$, not of $C\left(\mathbb R_+, \mathbb R\right)$.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: You are misusing the arbitrary union notation, $\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}A_{i}$ is the set of elements that are in some $A_{i}$, in particular $\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb R_+} \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)} c_t^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal C$ is a subset of $C\left(\mathbb R_+, \mathbb R^d\right)$ and not the family of subsets you are thinking of.

Comment: @FZan I think you are correct. I have edited my post.

Comment: I agree with you. The evaluation maps $c_t$ are into $\mathbb{R}^d$. Perhaps the author was halfway in between referring to $w\mapsto w(t)$ and $w\mapsto w_i(t)$, where $w(t)=(w_1(t), w_2(t),\ldots, w_d(t))\in \mathbb{R}^d$. But then the author would need the additional quantifier that these are measurable for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$.

This is equivalent to the intended condition, since $w\mapsto w(t)$ is measurable iff $w\mapsto w_i(t)$ is measurable for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$.